# my datagridview datasource throws a nullpointer reference

Tags: c#, datagridview, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to sort my Datagridview depending on the text in A textbox, but as soon as i put in a letter it throws a nullpointer. the datagridview was generated by visual studio 2013.

here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace KoolenEnKoolenApplication
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void debiteurBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.debiteurBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.knkDataSet);

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'knkDataSet.Debiteur' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.debiteurTableAdapter.Fill(this.knkDataSet.Debiteur);

    }

    private void debiteurDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            debiteurDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].ReadOnly = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("er is een error opgetreden");
        }

    }

    private void tbZpk_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (debiteurBindingSource.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = "Zpk like '%" + tbZpk.Text + "%'";
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Use the debugger, Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is the `DefaultView` that is null when you are debugging..?

In the example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

A new view is instantiated using the DataTable instance. e.g:

```
 // Create a DataView
 DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
```

Then use this view, rather than the `DefaultView`.
That's my best-guess to a resolution without seeing your designer code.